# Is it possible to detect position of Windows Phone 8 Tile?

Tags: windows-phone-8

On a windows phone 8 smart-phone the start screen contains a special kind of shortcuts to the applications installed on the device. They are called "Tiles". Tiles are more than shortcuts as they can contain brief information that is provided by the application behind it.

My question is: When programming such an application, am I able to get information on the actual position (row,column) of its related tile on the start screen from inside the application code?

I don't see any possibility to set this position, as in the common way of using the device, the user is the one who places the tiles on the screen. But I thought that it is at least possible to read the position.

Comment: As it's the user who decides where the tile is placed, why would your code need to know that information? It should be none of your concern where the user places the tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to this information is not possible via any public API.

It is not possible to tell if the main tile for an app is pinned, what size the tile is or where it is positioned.
If you create secondary tiles within the app it is possible to see if these still exist (via `ShellTile.ActiveTiles`) but you cannot know anything more about them (eg. size or position).

Comment: no good news, but thank you for answering anyways!